# Visa form asks what countries I've visited: does that include my home country?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm applying for a UK visa and the form asks, "Have you visited any other countries in the past 10 years?"  Do you have to list visits to your home country if you are applying from abroad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did visit your home country while living abroad, there's absolutely no harm in including it. So go ahead and add it to the list.

I wish there was more to add to this answer, but this is pretty much it.